# Why do we need separability?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

In topology a space X is said to be separable if there exist a countable subset of X s.t. it is dense in X.

My question is why it is so important this type of space?
I think that it is important because it acts just like countable sets, even though it can be uncountable, but I'm waiting for more detailed answer.

Comment: It keeps spaces in a manageable small size. For example a separable Hausdorff space has cardinality at most $2^{\mathfrak c}$. - Or Hilbert spaces have seaparble in their definition to allow working with nice series

Comment: Well, we probably don't _need_ separability. However, like most mathematical notions, it comes up in many natural examples. It also implies (either alone or together with other properties) more structure on spaces satisfying it (_e.g._, as Hagen von Eitzen states, a separable Hausdorff space has cardinality $\leq 2^{2^\omega}$, also separable paracompact spaces are Lindelöf), and also on spaces related to that given space (_e.g._, continuous images of separable spaces are separable, and the Hewitt–Marczewski–Pondiczery theorem: the product of $\leq 2^\omega$ separable spaces is separable).

Answer (score 5):

One nice property is that it controls the cardinality of mapping sets out of the space, making them act more like countable spaces than uncountable. More concretely, suppose $X$ is a separable space and consider the set of all continuous maps $X\to Y$ where $Y$ is some Hausdorff space - we'll call this space $C(X,Y)$.

Now, an upper bound for the cardinality of $C(X,Y)$ is $|Y|^{|X|}$ as this is the cardinality of the set of all function $X\to Y$ which is clearly a superset of $C(X,Y)$. Actually though, we can bring this cardinality down because $X$ is separable. Let $C$ be a countable infinite dense subset of $X$ and recall that if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a continuous map, then $f|_C\colon C\to Y$, the restriction of $f$ to $C$, extends uniquely to a continuous map $X\to Y$ because $C$ is dense and $Y$ is Hausdorff, and in fact it extends to $f$. We say that all continuous maps are determined by their restriction to $C$.

It follows that $|C(X,Y)|$ actually has an upper bound of $|Y|^{|C|}=|Y|^{\aleph_{0}}$. So, suppose $Y$ has the cardinality of the continuum, then $|C(X,Y)|$ has cardinalty at most $$\mathfrak{c}^{\aleph_0}=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak{c}$$ which is also clearly a lower bound, and so $|C(X,Y)|=\mathfrak{c}$. For instance, one special case is that $|C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})|=\mathfrak{c}<2^{\mathfrak{c}}=|\mathbb{R}|^{|\mathbb{R}|}$ - a surprising result.

Comment: For some reason, that last sentence makes me twitch uncontrollably.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The English or the mathematics? (I just changed the English so hopefully it reads better).

Comment: Oh, actually I can see how a set theorist would not like $|\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}|$ to be less than $2^{|\mathbb{R}|}$ :P. I guess that's a problem with topologists hijacking the exponential notation for mapping spaces.

Comment: Being pretty much right in the middle between (general) topology and set theory, I think it would be preferred to write $C(X,Y)$ in place of $Y^X$ for the set/space of continuous functions $X \to Y$.  (This is fairly standard notation, even if not quite as concise.)

Comment: Agreed, given the topic that is probably a better notation for this answer. I decided to go with it initially *because* I was working with cardinalities, but I can see now why that's actually a reason to stay away from the notation in this case.

Comment: Also, $Y$ must be Hausdorff to guarantee the uniqueness of the extension.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks.

Comment: I can breathe again!